# why does onDestroyView() not free my memory

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a widget, which opens a Fragment showing a list of contacts with their pictures. This Fragment consumes a lot of memory. On leaving the Fragment, the memory is still allocated...

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {    
        List<Contact> contacts = ContactHandler.getByGroup(group);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), contacts));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ...
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();   
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I figured out, that the remaining memory size is equal, regardless if I use the fragment with or without adding the adapter. So this is not my listview implementation. But > 20MB for an empty fragment seems for me a lot.

How can I tell the activity and fragment to free their memory?

Comment: BTW, your implementation of `onDestroyView()` is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java which relies on automatic Garbage Collection to free the memory. You have no control over when the memory is actually garbage collected (or freed). Make sure you don't keep a reference to the Fragment so it will eventually get garbage collected. If you suspect memory leaks try using LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

Comment: Before opening the Fragment the App uses 3MB, when the Fragment is visible it uses up to 45MB. After closing the Fragment und garbage collection it uses 27MB.

Comment: If you are sure the Garbage Collection was run and not enough memory being freed you may have a memory leak and need to track it down.
You cannot just tell the fragment to free everything. Things do not work this way. Search for 'android memory leak' on stack overflow and Google for more resources on the topic. LeakCanary is a useful tool for checking memory leaks and there is a good tech talk by the author here https://realm.io/news/droidcon-ricau-memory-leaks-leakcanary/ .